# Hyper-V Cut-n-Paste

Tags: vpn, hyper-v, rdp

I use Hyper-V on a development machine for multiple reasons and one of my biggest annoyances is that I can't cut and paste to/from the virtual machines.

I've been through all the options and can't find anything that seems like it would allow this.  Does anyone have any good solutions?

I have considered connecting via RDP to the VM instead of using the VPN Client, but one of my VMs is primarily used to connect via VPN to another network, and when I tried to RDP into that machine and then connect to the VPN (using Cisco AnyConnect), I got an error saying I could not connect to the VPN through an RDP session).

Comment: +1...I feel your pain. We have Hyper-V guests that need to use locked down VPN clients and cannot use RDP because of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Start your Hyper-V machine.
2. Ensure the "Enhanced Session" is disabled/unchecked via the hyper-v top window menu (View -> Enhanced Session).
3. Initiate and connect to your Cisco VPN client session.
4. Once your Cisco session is connected, check to re-enable the "Enhanced Session" menu choice again.
5. The enhanced cut-n-paste should work at this point.

*Note:* After step 4, my VM forced me to login to the workstation again. Strangely, my Cisco session was not disconnected. There may be some Cisco configuration that may disconnect in this circumstance and cripple this workaround.

*Note:* Using Cisco AnyConnect v 4.0, and Win10 as the VM

Comment: I'm not using this setup any more so I can't personally test it, but I have seen this work now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can paste text into the virtual machine (Clipboard -> Type Clipboard Text). It should work with Ctrl+V but it regularly doesn't for some reason.

What is annoying is that the Hyper-V manager and SCVMM say they use RDP to connect to the VMs so it should work. Although so should the mouse integration before installing the integration services but that doesn't either.

Comment: +1 for a half solution - now how about Copy (pulling data from the VM to either my host system or another VM)?

Comment: +1: Using RDP is far easier for ongoing use of the VMs.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't. My understanding of it is that they choose to have paste work by "typing" on the keyboard of the vm instead of using the Windows clipboard chaining stuff. Makes sense when you think it needs to work for more than just windows although a simple if(windows) would work.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the menu bar and unfold "screen" there is an option to turn on extensive session (or something like that, I don't know, I'm dutch.

If you turn it on, the client will reconnect and the clipboard is now shared.

Comment: This seems to be the setting that Mike also mentioned, however if you have that option enabled before you connect to the VPN, then the Cisco gives an error message.  See Mike E's answer above that seems to be the final piece.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case of wanting to RDP, then connect through VPN, you might try adding another NIC to the VM and using one for VPN and one for RDP.

Comment: I finally sat down to try this and unfortunately Cisco AnyConnect doesn't allow a VPN connection if you are RDPed into the machine, even if it is using a different NIC.

Answer (score 0):

Clunky but it works:
http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2008/01/15/understanding-the-clipboard-menu-under-hyper-v.aspx

Comment: Only to copy a screenshot and paste text, which is of limited use.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to close the VM window and login with Remote Desktop.  Clipboard sync works correctly thru RDP.

Comment: I don't think your answer is helpful.  the poster already explained why they can't use RDP  so saying to use RDP if not a useful answer.  maybe if you had suggested a way to usr RDP  with the vpn.